# ContentAssist delay on editors for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, perl

When using the Java Editor for Eclipse, one can set the ContentAssist delay to 0 seconds (in the Java Editor ContentAssist options). In other language editors, e.g EPIC (Perl Integration), this option isn't offered. However I guess that for all languages editors there is a configuration file where one can change this correctly, which is the same as for the Java Editor. So, where is the configuration file for the Eclipse Java Editor concerning the ContentAssist stuff? Thanks :-)

Comment: Apparently this exists in the latest version of EPIC: http://sourceforge.net/projects/e-p-i-c/forums/forum/258688/topic/5901157.  For other languages, I would not assume that it is in a config file if you aren't given the option.